# How to pre-order drupal commerce product when it is out of stock?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-commerce, drupal-rules

I am using Drupal Commerce 7 module. How it is possible to pre-order commerce product even it is showing out of stock ? For example - product will be shown out of stock but customer can pre-order that product and give payment, so when the product is available we can deliver it to customer. Is this possible, by which drupal module?

Answer (score 0):

Normally the functionality to prevent an out of stock product to be added to the cart is a [rule](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules). So to add an out of stock product to the cart you have these options:

1) Edit/Override the related rule.

2) Use a contrib module (that does the same thing) such as [commerce_stock](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_stock), [commerce_preorder](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_preorder) etc.